# Check if Product is in Category A, and not in Category B

Tags: category, products, tabs

I'm hoping someone can help me with the code to achieve the following... I'm working in the tabs.phtml file which is responsible for a custom tab on my product pages.

I need a function to check whether a product is in a certain category, but not in another category. In other words, If product A is in category with ID number 73, and it is NOT in category with ID number 83, then display the following custom tab...

The code I have so far works perfectly fine to check if a product is in either of the two categories, as seen here:

```
$yourCatIds = array(73,83);
$productCats = $p->getAvailableInCategories();

if (count(array_intersect($yourCatIds,$productCats)) && $currentProduct!="Gift") {

 code to display a certain tab goes here...
}
```

So how would I expand the above If statement to check if a product is in category 73, but not in category 83? You can ignore the $currentProduct!="Gift" part, as this is use to exclude products with a certain attribute.

I also don't need the code to actually display the tab, as I have this already. I just need the If statement.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to inspiration from @Raphael, I finally got it to work using the following statement:

```
$yourCatIdsNationwide = array(73);
$yourCatIdsDurbanOnly = array(83);

if (array_intersect($yourCatIdsDurbanOnly,$productCats) && !array_intersect($yourCatIdsNationwide,$productCats) && $currentProduct!="Gift") {
```

The above statement successfully checks if a product is in the category with the ID 83 and not in the category with ID 73, and does not have the product attribute value of "Gift" (a custom attribute I've created for my products).

I hope this helps anyone trying to achieve a similar thing...

Thank you Raphael for your help.

Brendon

Answer (score 0):

I reckon you can do the following

```
if(in_array(73,$productsCats) && !in_array(83,$productCats))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion Raphael. For some reason it didn't work using in_array, but thanks to your inspiration, I finally got it to work using array_intersect, but without count. I'll post it as an answer for others to reference. Thank you for your help.